# Make Java annotation act differently depending on field annotated

Tags: java, annotations, jackson

In Java, is there a way to change the behaviour of an annotation depending on the type of the annotated field?

I know that annotation presence is supposed to be tested by code. Not the opposite. But the case is rather particular: this is a Jackson 2.0 « inside » annotation which gather a list of annotations. We use it to define the field name (`@JsonProperty`) and the field serializing policies (`@JsonSerialize`).

The serialisation policies must be adapted to the annotated field. And, because we are talking of a framework, one unique annotation is far better than two separate ones.

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@JacksonAnnotationsInside.
@JsonProperty("_id")
@JsonSerialize(using=IdSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using=IdDeserializer.class)
public @interface Id {}
```

Some cases need to turn the serializers down, that's the point. In the following example, the `String` must be processed by the de/serializers, `ObjectId` don't. Both need to be renamed `_id` by the `@JsonProperty`.

```
public class Car {
    @Id String id
}

public class Bus {
    @Id ObjectId id
}
```

Any clues?

Comment: How do you plan to use the annotation ''@Id'' later on?

Comment: Ok I see the beauty in having one '@Id' instead of two '@Id1' '@Id2'... AFAIK annotations cannot have any behaviour, they are just tag-values so I think that a annotation-pure solution is discarded. Some ways to achieve what you want: (a) process those '@Id' annotations at deployment time using some framework such as BCEL (b) perhaps this could be done when loading the class using your custom class-loader (BCEL or others may support that approach) or (c) developing your custom (de)serializer ... Sorry I don't have experience with any so I cannot help you any further.

Comment: I've opened [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977144/create-a-type-aware-jackson-deserializer) focused on Jackson deserializer limitation