# parse json when json keys are the same with jackson

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

I have json that has same keys like shown in here

```
{
  "tests": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "object_type": "bla",
      "objects": {
        "id": 59,
        "company_name": "apple",
        "project_name": "iphone",
        "duration": 145
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 66,
      "object_type": "gla",
      "objects": {
        "id": 59,
        "institution_name": "Test",
        "subject": "Gsks",
        "duration": 2
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

When I am creating the class

A.class
List myClass;

```
TestClass.class

int id;
String object type;
@JsonProperty("objects")
Company objects1;
@JsonProperty("objects")
Subject objects2;
```

But when I want to parse it Jackson give me an error that can't parse because my class has 2 objects (I mean json has key objects which has body with different keys)

NOTE: I know I can parse it when I have one object... but I have to do this as I explained above.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Is this JSON you receive and have no choice in receiving or can you alter that JSON?

Comment: You can use inheritance here. and check the `fields` inside JSON before converting it back to object.

Comment: Worst case, Create a wrapper class and use it instead. Ex: Create `SubCompany` class containing all the fields. When you get the object back of `Objects` check which fields are present. Moreover you can send a `flag` from JSON itself and get the respective object from that like `getCompany` or `getSubject`

Comment: @ADi thanks for your comment. but I couldn't understand what you mean by that.. could you give me an example?

Comment: @fge I don't have an access to change that json I have to convert it using Jackson library.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977144/create-a-type-aware-jackson-deserializer

Comment: @pmb Please check the answer. I explained it in brief.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the Sfat's comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977144/create-a-type-aware-jackson-deserializer) can be one approach.

As per my comment,

I meant :

Create your `SubCompany` class as below containing all the fields from `Company` and `Subject` class.

```
public class SubCompany {
    //Just so you can ignore in Json 
    @JsonIgnore
    String type;

    int id;

    // All fields from Company Class
    String companyName;
    String projectName;
    int duration;

    //Remaining fields from Subject Class
    String institutionName;
    String subject;

    //Getters and Setters

    public SubCompany() {
        //At the end call method to test the type
        setType();
    }

    private void setType() {
        if (null != institutionName && null != subject)
            type = "Subject";
        else
            type = "Company";
    }

    //At this point the type is set so you know what you have Company or Subject
    //Now write customized writers.

    public Company getComany() {
        Company company = new Company();
        //Set all the fields accordingly.
        return company;
    }

    public Subject getSubject() {
        //In the similar fashion, write this method to get Subject.
    }

}
```

When you want to retrieve the `Subject` or `Company` Object after the de-serialization, you check what type of `SubCompany` is, and depending upon that, get the relevant object.

```
if(type.equals("Subject")
    Subject sub = subCompany.getSubject();
```